# How to export data from sqlite data base to excel file?

Tags: excel, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to export saved data from sqlite data base to an excel file?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to install the related ODBC driver for SQLite. Then connect via ODBC connector in Excel.

Or export as CSV and read CSV into Excel e.g. via SQLite CLI (or any DB GUI with SQLite support)

Or via Python read from SQLite and save as xlsx.